# multi variables in python like $$var in PHP

Tags: php, python

In PHP like below

```
<?php

$a = 'b'
$b = 'c'

echo $$a

?>
```

Output: c

Is there any similar kind of implementation in Python like $$..?

Answer (score 1):

no .... not really you can do stuff like

```
a = 'b'
b = 'c'

globals().getattr(a,None)
```

or even better **use a dict** (you should really do this!!!)

```
env = {'a':5,'b':'a'}
env[env['b']]
```

but there is nothing like `$$a`